# I want to get CCF Value from Sportradar MTS

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I wanted to get CCF Value from sportradar MTS.Without using API.

I used these dependency's,

```
implementation ("com.sportradar.mts.sdk:mts-sdk-doc:2.4.1.1")
implementation ("com.sportradar.mts.sdk:mts-sdk:2.4.1.1")
implementation("com.sportradar.mts.sdk.app:mts-sdk-app:2.4.1.1")
```

and I tryed

MtsClientApi.getCcf(String sourceId)

but inside MtsClientApi there is no getCcf().

I want to know How Can I get Ccf value?